# Generators of the additive integer group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My question is a simple one, perhaps it is more of a notational question but I am not sure.

In Dummit + Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, when introducing generators (page 26 section 1.2 Dihedral groups), they state that:

> For example, the integer 1 is a generator for the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers since every integer is a sum of a finite number of +1's and -1's, so $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 1\rangle$.

My question is that since every element of ($\mathbb{Z},+$) can be written with +1's and -1's, shouldn't the generator be $\langle 1,-1\rangle$? Or is it notation to not include the inverse elements.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle 1 \rangle$ is already a generator for $\mathbb{Z}$, because a generator also "generates" inverse elements.
This is due to the definition of a generator.

From Wikipedia:

> In abstract algebra, a generating set of a group is a subset such that every element of the group can be expressed as the combination (under the group operation) of finitely many elements of the subset and their **inverses**.

So $-3\in \langle 1 \rangle$, because we have $-3= (-1)+(-1)+(-1)$.

The same goes for $\langle -1\rangle$.

Also note that technically $\langle 1, -1\rangle$ is also a valid generator of the group, but it happens that there is also a "smaller" generator.

Comment: so essentially, a generator doesn't include its inverse? Because the way I am thinking about the generator $\langle 1\rangle$ is that given some integer (let's say 5) in $\mathbb{Z}$, we can "construct" it by 1+1+1+1+1. However we cannot do the same for the negative integers.

Comment: Oh never mind, I think I understand why you would not want to write down the inverse elements in a generator. Is it because the inverse is uniquely determined by the element in any group? Is that what you mean when you say "a generator 'generates' inverse elements" ?

Comment: No that is not correct. I did an edit so i hope it is a bit more clear now. In fact, a generator DOES include its inverse. What definition of generator are you using?

Comment: Oh! I think I understand what you were trying to say. Alright thank you, I appreciate your help!

Comment: One should be careful to distinguish between "a generator" and "a generating set". It is not accuse to write "$\langle -1,+1 \rangle$ is a generator", instead one should say it is a "generating set".